# Problems with kernel configuration on Lubuntu (APT, DPKG)

Tags: apt, kernel, lubuntu, dpkg

I have problem that is really bad.
When i do any kind of 'apt' command it gives me a fatal error about kernel configuration :

```
wupeq@WiktorPendrive:~$ sudo apt autoremove
[sudo] password for wupeq: 
Czytanie list pakietów... Gotowe
Budowanie drzewa zależności... Gotowe
Odczyt informacji o stanie... Gotowe   
0 aktualizowanych, 0 nowo instalowanych, 0 usuwanych i 0 nieaktualizowanych.
4 nie w pełni zainstalowanych lub usuniętych.
Po tej operacji zostanie dodatkowo użyte 0 B miejsca na dysku.
Konfigurowanie pakietu linux-image-5.13.0-30-generic (5.13.0-30.33) ...
Failed to create symlink to vmlinuz-5.13.0-19-generic: Operation not permitted at /usr/bin/linux-update-symlinks line 64.
dpkg: błąd przetwarzania pakietu linux-image-5.13.0-30-generic (--configure):
 podproces zainstalowany pakiet linux-image-5.13.0-30-generic skrypt post-installation zwrócił kod błędu 1
dpkg: problemy z zależnościami uniemożliwiają skonfigurowanie pakietu linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-30-generic:
 linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-30-generic zależy od linux-image-5.13.0-30-generic | linux-image-unsigned-5.13.0-30-generic; jednakże:
  Pakiet linux-image-5.13.0-30-generic nie jest jeszcze skonfigurowany.
  Pakiet linux-image-unsigned-5.13.0-30-generic nie jest zainstalowany.

dpkg: błąd przetwarzania pakietu linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-30-generic (--configure):
 problemy z zależnościami - pozostawianie nieskonfigurowanego
dpkg: problemy z zależnościami uniemożliwiają skonfigurowanie pakietu linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic zależy od linux-image-5.13.0-30-generic; jednakże:
  Pakiet linux-image-5.13.0-30-generic nie jest jeszcze skonfigurowany.
 linux-image-generic zależy od linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-30-generic; jednakże:
  Pakiet linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-30-generic nie jest jeszcze skonfigurowany.

dpkg: błąd przetwarzania pakieBrak raportu programu apport, ponieważ komunikat błędu wskazuje, że przyczyna niepowodzenia leży w poprzednim błędzie.
                                                                                                                                                    Brak raportu programu apport, ponieważ komunikat błędu wskazuje, że przyczyna niepowodzenia leży w poprzednim błędzie.
                                                                             Brak raportu programu apport, ponieważ osiągnięto limit MaxReports
                                                                                                                                               tu linux-image-generic (--configure):
 problemy z zależnościami - pozostawianie nieskonfigurowanego
dpkg: problemy z zależnościami uniemożliwiają skonfigurowanie pakietu linux-generic:
 linux-generic zależy od linux-image-generic (= 5.13.0.30.40); jednakże:
  Pakiet linux-image-generic nie jest jeszcze skonfigurowany.

dpkg: błąd przetwarzania pakietu linux-generic (--configure):
 problemy z zależnościami - pozostawianie nieskonfigurowanego                                                                                                                                
Wystąpiły błędy podczas przetwarzania:                                                                                                                                                       
 linux-image-5.13.0-30-generic                                                                                                                                                               
 linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-30-generic                                                                                                                                                       
 linux-image-generic                                                                                                                                                                         
 linux-generic                                                                                                                                                                               
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Do you guys know what could cause that?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is something wrong with your kernel installation.
linux-image-5.13.0-30-generic

You could try to re-install it.